# Why is my udev mounted device not staying put?

Tags: centos, mount, udev

I have a computer running CentOS 7.  I'm trying to set up a udev rule to automatically mount a USB drive (named 'sdb1') to /mnt/flash whenever it is connected.

The udev script was not working (see below), so I instead put my commands into a bash script and had udev run the bash script so I could see what was going on.

**Problem #1:**
If I try to directly create /mnt/flash from my bash script, it fails due to the root filesystem being read-only.  I can confirm the root filesystem is NOT read-only.  My system is already booted.  However, if I insert my USB drive, let udev run my script, sure enough when I run 'mount | logger' in my script it shows root is read only.

I worked around this issue by running 'mount -o remount,rw /' at the top of my script.

**Problem #2:**  I'm able to create /mnt/flash and mount /dev/sdb1 to /mnt/flash successfully.  I run 'mount | logger' after doing this and see it mounted in /var/log/messages.  However, when all is said and done, /dev/sdb1 is not mounted.  I even put a 5 second delay in my script and ran 'mount | logger' a second time.  Both times show /dev/sdb1 is mounted to /mnt/flash.  However, if I run 'mount' from a different terminal while all of this is going on, I never see /dev/sdb1 mounted anywhere.

Am I going crazy, or is udev doing some strange things to the filesystems while it runs?

udev script:  /etc/udev/rules.d/99-usb-automount.rules

```
#Only operate on sdb1
KERNEL!="sdb1", GOTO="usb-automount-end"
ACTION=="add", PROGRAM!="/sbin/blkid %N", GOTO="usb-automount-end"

#import useful variables from blkid program
IMPORT{program}="/sbin/blkid -o udev -p %N"

#ignore anything other than vfat filesystems
ACTION=="add", ENV{ID_FS_TYPE}!="vfat", GOTO="usb-automount-end"

#remount root as read-write.  Not sure why we have to do this!
#ACTION=="add", RUN+="/bin/mount -o remount,rw /"

#mount to /mnt/flash
#ACTION=="add", RUN+="/bin/mkdir -p /mnt/flash"
#ACTION=="add", RUN+="/bin/mount -t vfat -o dmask=000,fmask=111 /dev/%k /mnt/flash"
ACTION=="add", RUN+="/root/test_run.sh", OPTIONS="last_rule"

#clean up after removal
#ACTION=="remove", RUN+="/bin/umount -l /mnt/flash"

#label for goto end
LABEL="usb-automount-end"
```

Here is /root/test_run.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash -x
logger "running mount"
mount | logger
logger "remounting root"
mount -o remount,rw /  2>&1 | logger
logger "remount done"
mount | logger
logger "Running script.  Adding dir"
mkdir -p /mnt/flash2 2>&1 | logger
logger "Directory added... mounting."
mount -t vfat -o dmask=000,fmask=111 /dev/sdb1 /mnt/flash2 2>&1 | logger
logger "Mounted"
mount | logger

logger "Sleeping 5 then re-checking"
sleep 5

mount | logger
```

**Edit 1 :** Disabling SELinux fixed problem #1.  However, I still cannot get the /dev/sdb1 to stay mounted after udev.  It still appears there is almost a second mount table that is maintained from within the udev context.

Comment: As to the read-only problem, check `dmesg` and udev's logs to make sure the file system is not being mounted read-only because it has an error, or wasn't cleanly unmounted.  You might need to run the right flavor of `fsck` on it.

Comment: The filesystem is only mounted read-only from the perspective of the script run by udev.  When I login and view the output of 'mount' it shows as read-write.  I did check dmesg and don't see any related errors.

Comment: its almost like devmapper is running your commands within a container.

Comment: It does seem appear to be something like that.  Is that possible?  I haven't modified much on my CentOS 7 distro.  It is running KDE instead of the default gnome, however.

Comment: try testing with selinux disabled `setenforce 0`

Comment: After disabling Selinux, the root filesystem no longer appears to be ready-only from the udev context.  However, my 'mount' command still does not persist outside of the udev script.  The last 'mount' command in my script above shows /dev/sdb1 mounted on /mnt/flash2.  However, after completion I don't see it mounted from a root shell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Problem #1** was caused by SELinux.  Since I don't need it for this system, I simply disabled it.

**Problem #2** was caused by a udev setting (specified in systemd script) that makes the udev namespace keep a 'slave' copy of the mount flags.  Changing this to 'shared' fixed the problem.  See a more detailed answer here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/154318/41988