# udev won't mount the plugged in device

Tags: arch-linux, mount, udev

I'm trying to automount a USB device upon plugin but it refuses to mount. I set a rule to execute the following script :

```
#!/bin/bash
mkdir /media/mnt
echo AFTER MKDIR > /home/output
sleep 5
echo AFTER SLEEP >> /home/output
mount /dev/sdb1 /media/mnt
echo $? >> /home/output
echo AFTER MOUNT >> /home/output
```

The script gets executed nicely, `lsblk` shows that `/dev/sdb1` is present, `output` contain all the echoes, yet `sdb1` won't be mounted in `/media/mnt`. The mount command exit code is `0`

When I execute the mount command in that script manually after the USB device is plugged in it mounts it without problem.

Comment: Where did you set that rule?  Is it run by `root`?  Perhaps adding a line in your script to validate the effective UID might be a good idea: `id >> /home/output`

Comment: @JuliePelletier in `/etc/udev/rules.d` both the script and the rule where made by root. id returns root

Comment: Are you using systemd?

Comment: @meuh no I'm using udev that calls the script in OP

Comment: But is your archlinux configured to use systemd for most things?

Answer (score 2):

Had to add `MountFlags=shared` in `/usr/lib/systemd/system/systemd-udevd.service`, whatever this is. See [mount is not executed when called by udev](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/152485/mount-is-not-executed-when-called-by-udev/154318#154318)