# Why is my udev-fired script not working?

Tags: bash, shell, udev

I created a udev rule in order to sync my USB drive with my documents folder, but it doesn't seem to be working.

**95-usb-auto-sync.rules**:

```
ACTION=="add", ATTRS{idVendor}=="0930", ATTRS{idProduct}=="1408", RUN+="/home/riccardo/Documents/Scripts/sync-riccardo-usb.sh"
```

**/home/riccardo/Documents/Scripts/sync-riccardo-usb.sh**:

```
#!/bin/bash

rsync -a --delete '/home/riccardo/Documents/Development/' '/run/media/riccardo/Riccardo/Documents/Development' --exclude='*/node_modules' >> /home/riccardo/Documents/Scripts/log.txt
rsync -a --delete '/home/riccardo/Documents/KiCAD/' '/run/media/riccardo/Riccardo/Documents/KiCAD' >> /home/riccardo/Documents/Scripts/log.txt
rsync -a --delete '/home/riccardo/Documents/Personal Files/' '/run/media/riccardo/Riccardo/Documents/Personal Files' >> /home/riccardo/Documents/Scripts/log.txt
rsync -a --delete '/home/riccardo/Documents/Scripts/' '/run/media/riccardo/Riccardo/Documents/Scripts' >> /home/riccardo/Documents/Scripts/log.txt
```

I added the '>> /home/riccardo/Documents/Scripts/log.txt' part to check if the script was actually executed. The log.txt file remained blank though.

**Toshiba USB Drive Udev info**:

```
  looking at device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb4/4-2':
    KERNEL=="4-2"
    SUBSYSTEM=="usb"
    DRIVER=="usb"
    ATTR{authorized}=="1"
    ATTR{avoid_reset_quirk}=="0"
    ATTR{bConfigurationValue}=="1"
    ATTR{bDeviceClass}=="00"
    ATTR{bDeviceProtocol}=="00"
    ATTR{bDeviceSubClass}=="00"
    ATTR{bMaxPacketSize0}=="9"
    ATTR{bMaxPower}=="296mA"
    ATTR{bNumConfigurations}=="1"
    ATTR{bNumInterfaces}==" 1"
    ATTR{bcdDevice}=="0001"
    ATTR{bmAttributes}=="80"
    ATTR{busnum}=="4"
    ATTR{configuration}==""
    ATTR{devnum}=="2"
    ATTR{devpath}=="2"
    ATTR{idProduct}=="1408"
    ATTR{idVendor}=="0930"
    ATTR{ltm_capable}=="no"
    ATTR{manufacturer}=="TOSHIBA"
    ATTR{maxchild}=="0"
    ATTR{product}=="USB FLASH DRIVE"
    ATTR{quirks}=="0x0"
    ATTR{removable}=="removable"
    ATTR{serial}=="C03FD5FBA9CDC1401D7FB227"
    ATTR{speed}=="5000"
    ATTR{urbnum}=="11182"
    ATTR{version}==" 3.00"
```

Thank you,

Riccardo

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`man udev` explains that the `RUN+=` key should not be used for long running tasks:

> This can only be used for very short-running foreground tasks. Running an event process for a long period of time may block all further events
>              for this or a dependent device.
>
> Starting daemons or other long-running processes is not appropriate for udev; the forked processes, detached or not, will be unconditionally
>              killed after the event handling has finished.

The correct approach, for modern systems that use systemd, is `SYSTEMD_WANTS`. From `man systemd.device`:

> THE UDEV DATABASE
>
> The settings of device units may either be configured via unit files, or directly from the udev database (which is recommended). The following udev
>          device properties are understood by systemd:
>
> SYSTEMD_WANTS=, SYSTEMD_USER_WANTS=
>              Adds dependencies of type Wants from the device unit to all listed units. The first form is used by the system systemd instance, the second by
>              user systemd instances. Those settings may be used to activate arbitrary units when a specific device becomes available.
>
> Note that this and the other tags are not taken into account unless the device is tagged with the "systemd" string in the udev database, because
>              otherwise the device is not exposed as a systemd unit (see above).

So, your udev rule would become:

```
ACTION=="add", ATTRS{idVendor}=="0930", ATTRS{idProduct}=="1408", SYSTEMD_WANTS="rsync_backup.service"
```

And you write a service file to call your backup script when the device is mounted:

```
[Unit]
Description=Backup riccardo's stuff
Requires=media-Riccardo.mount
After=media-Riccardo.mount

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/rsync_backup_thing

[Install]
WantedBy=media-Riccardo.mount
```

When `/media/Riccardo` is mounted, your bash script will be triggered.

Comment: Great answer! Do the 'Required' and 'After' Entries need to be modified? I replaced my systemd unit with your definition and it's not firing when I connect the device - [here are the files](https://gist.github.com/Kopharex/4794f08ce818a11502c265e1d5759236)

Comment: They just ensure that `/media/Riccardo` is mounted before running the script, to prevent you rsync'ing onto an unmounted target. Make sure that `/media/Riccardo` is actually the destination (I just used that as an example).

Comment: How should I modify that if my drive is mounted in '/run/media/riccardo/Riccardo' rather that '/media/Riccardo'?

Comment: The syntax is the same: `run-media-riccardo-Riccardo.mount` (the slashes are changed to dashes and `.mount` is appended).

Comment: Thank you very much. One last question: My device seems to be changing name when it is mounted. Would you happen to know a way to make it always use the same mount directory?

Comment: Label it: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RenameUSBDrive

Comment: I did, but it's being automatically mounted to 'Riccardo1'. I also noticed a Riccardo directory was created, perhaps by the systemd service?

Comment: That is an entirely separate issue (and is related to how you unmount the device).

Comment: Okay i deleted the directory and now it's mounting correctly, but i'm gettin this from systemd: /usr/lib/systemd/system/usb-auto-sync.service:3: Failed to add dependency on run-media-riccardo-Riccardo

Comment: Getting this when i try to start the service manually: Failed to start usb-auto-sync.service: Unit run-media-riccardo-Riccardo.mount is masked

Comment: Failed to add dependency on run-media-riccardo-Riccardo was from before i added .mount, it's fixed now. But the service remains inactive when i plug in the drive.

Comment: getting this now: Failed to start usb-auto-sync.service: Unit run-media-riccardo-Riccardo.mount not found.

Answer (score 2):

As @jasonwryan suggested I changed the udev rule to:

```
ACTION=="add", ATTRS{idVendor}=="0930", ATTRS{idProduct}=="1408", ENV{SYSTEMD_WANTS}="usb-auto-sync.service"
```

with usb-auto-sync.service:

```
[Unit]
Description=Auto Sync USB

[Service]
ExecStart=/home/riccardo/Documents/Scripts/sync-riccardo-usb.sh
StandardOutput=null

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
Alias=usbauto-sync.service
```

I enabled the service and now the script is firing.

Comment: Hi There, what does the actual mounting of your USB drive? Cheers