# Application started by Udev rule closes after 4 seconds

Tags: arch-linux, kde, udev

File `/etc/udev/rules.d/90-test.rules`:

```
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ENV{DISPLAY}=":0", ENV{HOME}="/home/user", RUN+="/etc/udev/rules.d/test.sh"
```

File `/etc/udev/rules.d/test.sh`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
/usr/bin/kcalc &
```

When I plug in an USB device, kcalc starts as expected (2 times because the rule is kept simple). But after 4 to 5 seconds, kcalc closes again. I also tried it with `nohup` but without success. Same occurs for other applications like `konsole` and `kate`.

When I don't run kcalc in the background (no `&`), it doesn't close but it seems like further processing is blocked. The Device Notifier notifies me only after I closed kcalc. I dislike this solution because it affects other parts of the system.

So why do the applications close and how can I prevent it?

Comment: A related question is https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/378133/5132 .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [udev manpage](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/udev.html)

> Starting daemons or other long-running processes is not appropriate for udev; the forked processes, detached or not, will be unconditionally killed after the event handling has finished.

Thus, the best way is to use `udev` to trigger a `systemd` service that ultimately starts your script, as in

```
RUN{program}="/bin/systemctl start my_service.service"
```

where you have to write the appropriate `.service` file.